# Can't connect to the selenoid. Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /ip.add.re.ss:80

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, selenoid

I have launched selenoid on the my AWS server.
I followed official tutorial: https://aerokube.com/cm/latest/

And started selenoid (+ui) in the following way:

```
cm selenoid start --vnc
cm selenoid-ui start --port 8081
```

Ports 4444 and 80 are opened in security group (both - in inbound and outbound rules)

Now I try to use selenoid remotely and setup webdriver:

```java
        ChromeOptions newOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        newOptions.setCapability("enableVNC", true);
        newOptions.setCapability("enableVideo", false);
        newOptions.setCapability("sessionTimeout", "3m");
        URL host;

        try {
            host = new URL(SELENOID_HUB);// -> http://x.xx.x.xx:4444/wd/hub
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(host, newOptions);
        driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
        return new ChromeDriver();
```

After code execution I receive error on the line `RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(host, newOptions);`:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /x.xx.xx.x:80

Full stacktrace:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:
> Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of
> the remote server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version:
> '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System
> info: host: 'DESKTOP-DT9E80O', ip: '192.168.0.113', os.name: 'Windows
> 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'
> Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver  at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
> at
> slotgentesting.configuration.DriverProvider.initChromeDriver(DriverProvider.java:68)
> at
> slotgentesting.configuration.DriverProvider.initDriver(DriverProvider.java:46)
> at
> slotgentesting.configuration.DriverProvider.getDriver(DriverProvider.java:84)
> at slotgentesting.actions.BaseAction.(BaseAction.java:9)  at
> slotgentesting.actions.demo.DemoLoginPageAction.(DemoLoginPageAction.java:11)
> ... 50 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect
> to /x.x.x.xx:80   at
> okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)  at
> okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
> at
> okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
> at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
> ... 58 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed
> out: no further information   at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)   at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)     at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:549)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
> at
> java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)   at
> okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
> at
> okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
> ... 80 more

- Additional info:

I have access to the http://x.xx.x.xx:4444/wd/hub from my browser and checked it in the PowerShell terminal:

```bash
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName x.x.x.x.x -Port 4444
```

result:

> ComputerName     : x.x.x.x
> RemoteAddress    : x.x.x.x
> RemotePort       : 4444
> InterfaceAlias   : Wi-Fi
> SourceAddress    : 192.168.0.113
> TcpTestSucceeded : True

Comment: In error message you have port 80, but Selenoid is running on 4444. Check your code.

Comment: @vania-pooh I determined that the reason of error was selenide dependency. I removed this dependency and have a new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75678878/selenoid-calls-server-freezing
Could you analyze that question? I will delete currently...

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, the reason (in my case) was `selenoid` dependency. I not sure, but after I deleted it I received more properly error `Failed to connect to /ip.add.re.ss:4444`. But, in the end after I increased memory capacity to 8 Gb in the AWS instance all started work properly.

So, at least, definitely, the memory must be enough on the server.